# How can i use private frameworks in my ios application

Tags: iphone, ios, core-bluetooth

I'm working on changing bluetooth settings from iphone application programatically.I got to know that there a private framework called BluetoothManager which meets my requirement.But as it is a private framework i could be able to import it like we import the other frameworks.How to import the private frameworks into my iphone application? moreover without any apple provided header files how can we access the functionalities from those private frameworks.can anyone suggest me me?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

copy new framework in your project and then import in your project
Click on add other button and select from your project which you have already copy in your file[image]